# ffmpeg on Linux Mint only rotates videos 180 degrees, won't do 90 degrees

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm attempting to rotate a landscape mp4 video into a portrait mp4 video using ffmpeg 2.8.6 on Linux Mint.

The well-known way to do this is with the command:

```
ffmpeg -i VID_20160925_082146.mp4 -vf "transpose=1" Leaf.mp4
```

The result I'm getting is a 180 degree (or flipped) mp4, still in landscape mode.

Using 0, 2, and 3 for transpose values does no better.

Another suggested command was:

```
ffmpeg -i VID_20160925_082146.mp4 -c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=90 Leaf.mp4
```

Same effect.

I used to use avconv for doing this, but it's now just a link to ffmpeg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your video has a rotation tag (of -90 deg)  in it.

Try

```
ffmpeg -noautorotate -i VID_20160925_082146.mp4 -vf "transpose=1" -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 Leaf.mp4
```

Comment: Well there ya' go! Thanks!